# ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing ORA-24333: zero iteration count

Tags: plsql

I am getting the following errors while executing the below procedure. Please help me find the solution. I am really very new to XML using in Oracle. Your help is really appreciated.

```
PROCEDURE sp_fcp_extract is
     v_xml dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
     xmloutput clob;
     v_taxid number;
     v_coid NUMBER;
     v_prod varchar2(10);
     v_disp varchar2(200);

     cursor Rev_cur is select * from t_uar_reviews where CREATED_DATE='17-MAY-17' ;
       r Rev_cur%rowtype;
      cursor case_cur( c_revid IN t_uar_reviews.uar_review_id%type )
          is select *
               from t_uar_cases where uar_review_id= c_revid ;
     c case_cur%rowtype;
   begin
    open Rev_cur;
    loop
       fetch Rev_cur into r;
       exit when Rev_cur%notfound;
       open case_cur( r.uar_review_id );
       loop
         fetch case_cur into c;
         exit when case_cur%notfound;

    BEGIN
        select H.ssn_taxid_ind into v_taxid  from  wells.t_hogan_acct_cust_month h 
       where nvl(c.acct_nmbr,0) = nvl(regexp_replace(h.v_acct_num,'[^[:digit:]]'),0) ;

              select ref.CIS_COID,ref.CIS_PROD into v_coid,v_prod from wells.t_hogan_cust_xref ref where c.ecn=ref.CIS_CUST_ECN ;

        select d.disposition_desc into v_disp from t_disposition d where r.disposition_id=d.disposition_id ;

     EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
       THEN
        NULL;
   END;


         v_xml := DBMS_XMLGen.newContext('<BUSINESS_INDICATOR_ID>1</BUSINESS_INDICATOR_ID > ' ||
                 '<RECEIVED_DATE>' ||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')|| '</RECEIVED_DATE>' ||
                 '<ZONE_ID>1</ZONE_ID>' ||
                 '<ORIGINATOR_LAN_ID>' || r.REVIEWED_BY || '</ORIGINATOR_LAN_ID> ' ||
                 '<ORIGINATOR_AU>0070705</ORIGINATOR_AU>' ||
                 '<EVENT_DESCRIPTION>' || r.SUMMARY_NOTE || '</EVENT_DESCRIPTION> ' ||
                 '<FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' || (c.exposure_amt) || '</FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT> '||   --sum(exposure_amt)
                 '<ALERT_ID>' ||r.UAR_REVIEW_ID || '</ALERT_ID>' ||
                 '<CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID>' || v_taxid || '</CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID> ' ||
                 '<ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_NUMBER>' || c.ecn ||'</ENTERPRISE_CUSTOMER_NUMBER> '||
                 '<TAX_ID_NUMBER>' || c.tax_id ||'</TAX_ID_NUMBER> ' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>' || c.acct_nmbr ||'</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_COMPANY_NUMBER>' || v_coid || '</ACCOUNT_COMPANY_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_CODE>' || v_prod ||'</ACCOUNT_PRODUCT_CODE>' ||
                -- '<EVENT_UAR_FRAUD_ATTACHMENT>' || wells.t_file_attachment ||'</EVENT_UAR_FRAUD_ATTACHMENT>' ||
                -- '<FILE_NAME>' ||wells.t_file_attachment||'</FILE_NAME>' ||
                 '<DISPOSITON_STATUS_NAME>' || v_disp || '</DISPOSITON_STATUS_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_TYPE_NAME>' || c.case_type ||'</CASE_TYPE_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_NUMBER>' || c.case_nmbr||'</CASE_NUMBER>' ||
                 '<FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' || c.exposure_amt ||'</FRAUD_POTENTIAL_LOSS_AMOUNT>' ||
                 '<LAST_COMPANY_NAME>' || c.full_name||'</LAST_COMPANY_NAME>' ||
                 '<CASE_OPEN_DATE>' || to_char(c.created_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')||'</CASE_OPEN_DATE>' ||
                 '<CASE_CLOSE_DATE>' || to_char(c.close_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ||'</CASE_CLOSE_DATE>' ||
                 '<CRIME_RING_ID>' || c.ring_id ||'</CRIME_RING_ID>' ||
                 '<CRIME_RING_NAME>  </CRIME_RING_NAME>' ||
                 '<SOR_PARENT_CASE_ID>' || c.uar_case_id ||'</SOR_PARENT_CASE_ID>');

         xmloutput := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_xml);
            dbms_output.put_line(xmloutput);


       end loop;
       close case_cur;
     end loop;
     close Rev_cur;
  end;
```

And the error am getting

ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-24333: zero iteration count
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 7
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 147
ORA-06512: at line 69
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"
*Cause:    An error occurred when processing the XML function

Please suggest me some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're using the wrong function. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS69856 It expects a ctxHandle or a SQL

Comment: have a look at https://communities.actian.com/s/article/Oracle-Query-Error-ORA-24333-zero-iteration-count  I note that you have a cople of lies commented out in your XML try removing these commented out lines and see how you go.